Add second argument to functions
I would like to add an argument to the code given below from this thread.
import Numeric.GSL.ODE
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra
import Numeric.AD

vanderpol :: Vector Double  -- ^ Time points
         -> [Vector Double]
vanderpol ts = toColumns $
         odeSolveV (BSimp $ \t -> fromLists . jac t . toList)
                   0.1 1e-8 1e-8
                   (\t -> fromList . xdot t . toList)
                   (fromList [0.5,0]) ts
 where xdot :: Num a => a -> [a] -> [a]
       xdot t [x,v] = [v, -x*(1-x^2)]
       jac :: Double -> [Double] -> [[Double]]
       jac t = jacobian (xdot $ realToFrac t)

However, I can't seem to figure out how I would do this. My idea was something like this, where we pass mu to xdot, which I think causes a need to also pass mu to jac.
import Numeric.GSL.ODE
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra
import Numeric.AD

vanderpol :: Vector Double  -- ^ Time points
         -> [Vector Double]
vanderpol ts = toColumns $
         odeSolveV (BSimp $ \t -> fromLists . jac t mu . toList)
                   0.1 1e-8 1e-8
                   (\t -> fromList . xdot t mu . toList)
                   (fromList [0.5,0]) ts
 where xdot :: Num a => a -> [a] -> [a]
       xdot t mu [x,v] = [v, -x*mu*(1-x^2)]
       jac :: Double -> [Double] -> [[Double]]
       jac t = jacobian (xdot $ realToFrac t mu)
       mu = 2 :: Double

How can I edit this code so that I may pass a Double or a (Double, Double) to xdot? Would this require an edit of jac?

You might need jac t mu = jacobian (xdot (realToFrac t) mu). You need to adjust the types as well e.g. xdot :: Num a => a -> a -> ... and jac :: Double -> Double -> ...

It's not clear why you'd want to pass μ as an argument to xdot. This doesn't make sense to me, the ODE solver wouldn't be able to use / fill in this argument. What seems more reasonable is just to have it as a constant parameter, like you already do by declaring it in the where block (or as an argument to vanderpol). That works in principle is it is, no reason to explicitly pass around mu. What is required is that this is a polymorphic value, i.e. mu :: Num a => a; mu = 2 instead of 2 :: Double. (Can also be Fractional or Floating; the constraint on xdot would have to adapt.)

The hint provided by @chi was enough help to fix my code. I've felt this need to pass mu to xdot as in another example where I implement this the equation of xdot is dependent on mu, and I have several calls to xdot where mu varies. This was the most straightforward method to fix that for me, as in that version xdot is so large I declared it outside of vanderpol (I think it is called top-level here). But if you have any other way to implement what I said, if it made any sense, feel free to share with this beginner.

This is not the VanderPol oscillator. For that xdot has to be [v, -x + mu*(1-x^2)*v ].

@LutzLehmann I know. It's just a remnant from a previous example.

The question in the link had it right, only the answer had this likely copy-paste error.

As per @leftroundabout's comment, you don't need to make mu a parameter of xdot or jac, but it's tricky to get the types right here.  If you want to pass mu as a parameter to vanderpol, the secret is that mu needs to have a general enough type that it can be used as both a Double (as required by xdot in the fifth argument of odeSolveV and as a ReverseDouble s, the weird type required by the ad package jacobian function.
It's not sufficient to define it as a general polymorphic type:
vanderpol :: Num a => a     -- Not polymorphic enough!
          -> Vector Double
          -> [Vector Double]
vanderpol mu ts = ...

because a specific use of vanderpol will want to specialize mu to a specific numeric type a, which can be either Double or ReverseDouble s, but not both at once.  Instead, you need a higher-rank type:
vanderpol :: (forall a. (Num a) => a)   -- rank 2 type
          -> Vector Double
          -> [Vector Double]
vanderpol mu ts = ...

then it'll work.
The following appears to type check okay.  Note that mu only appears as an argument to vanderpol and at its point of use within xdot, just like a normal mu parameter:
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Numeric.GSL.ODE
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra
import Numeric.AD.Mode.Reverse.Double

vanderpol :: (forall a. (Num a) => a)
         -> Vector Double  -- ^ Time points
         -> [Vector Double]
vanderpol mu ts = toColumns $
         odeSolveV (BSimp $ \t -> fromLists . jac t . toList)
                   0.1 1e-8 1e-8
                   (\t -> fromList . xdot t . toList)
                   (fromList [0.5,0]) ts
 where xdot t [x,v] = [v, -x*mu*(1-x^2)]
       jac t = jacobian (xdot t)

When you actually use vanderpol, you'll have to ensure that its first argument is "general enough".  So this works:
main = print $ vanderpol 2 (fromList [1,2,3])

but this doesn't:
main = do
    mu <- readLn
    print $ vanderpol mu (fromList [1,2,3])

because you can't readLn in a coefficient with an unspecified type.
Update: As @leftroundabout pointed out, in this case it might be better to accept mu as a Double and then convert it to the needed type with realToFrac, so the following works, too, without the need for a higher-rank type:
vanderpol :: Double            -- mu is a Double
          -> Vector Double
          -> [Vector Double]
vanderpol mu ts = toColumns $
         odeSolveV (BSimp $ \t -> fromLists . jac t . toList)
                   0.1 1e-8 1e-8
                   (\t -> fromList . xdot t . toList)
                   (fromList [0.5,0]) ts
 where xdot t [x,v] = [v, -x*realToFrac mu*(1-x^2)]
     -- we convert it here:  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       jac t = jacobian (xdot t)


An alternative is to take the argument as Double but then generalise it, like vanderpol μ' t = ... where μ :: Fractional a => a; μ = realToFrac μ'. Indeed realToFrac is also needed in jac.

(Note that I didn't need the realToFrac call in the definition of jac, because t is actually an unused dummy parameter left over from the original example.)
